# Hyperledger Fabric: The following staticcheck issues were flagged make: *** [Makefile:186: linter] Error 1

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

While trying to setup the dev environment for Hyperledger Fabric 2.2, I am getting this error in the 'make dist-clean all' command execution

```
All files have SPDX-License-Identifier headers
Building github.com/client9/misspell/cmd/misspell -> misspell
Checking changed go files for spelling errors ...
spell checker passed
Checking for go:generate parent path references
Checking trailing spaces ...
DEP: Checking for dependency issues..
./scripts/check_deps.sh
Building golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports -> goimports
Building mvdan.cc/gofumpt -> gofumpt
Building honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck -> staticcheck
LINT: Running code checks..
./scripts/golinter.sh
Checking with goimports
Checking with gofumpt
Checking for golang.org/x/net/context
Checking for github.com/gogo/protobuf
Checking with go vet
Checking with staticcheck
The following staticcheck issues were flagged
vendor/github.com/dustin/go-humanize/number.go:76:9: constant overflow (compile)
vendor/github.com/onsi/ginkgo/internal/leafnodes/benchmarker.go:82:25: constant overflow (compile)
make: *** [Makefile:186: linter] Error 1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What Go version are you using?

Comment: go version go1.17.1 linux/amd64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the releases page for fabric https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases it will tell you which version of Go should be used to build that tagged version of fabric. If you are building off of the release branch then you should check the code to see which Go version to use, using any other version can have issues (as you have seen). Currently 2.2.4 and 2.2 use goLang 1.16.7 (at time of writing). If you are looking to contribute moving to newer versions of GoLang then you need to investigate and fix any build breaks as part of that migration

Comment: Yes. The setup page https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/dev-setup/devenv.html says Go version 1.15.x. But when doing the make checks it says 1.16.7. So I downgraded to 1.16.7 and now it is working

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have raised a github issue about the out of date documentation

Comment: Can you look at this issue. https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-questions?msg=mncfkz4q5QFkbkDLP. Getting this issue after fixing the one here. Should I create a new SO post for this?

Comment: Might be better for a new SO as someone who knows more than me would hopefully be able to help, I just know about the process of fabric moving GoLang versions and what's involved rather than actually having done it myself